# Was the Mishkan in Shiloh destroyed?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle

The gemarah Megillah 16b indicates that the Mishkan in Shiloh was destroyed. There does not seem to be any outright statement in the pesukim that this is the case. It says (Shmuel Alef chapter 4) that the aron was taken captive, but does not explicitly state that the entire Mishkan was destroyed, which I would take to mean the full structure was completely decimated in a manner similar to the way the temples were destroyed.

From where do we know that the Mishkan in Shiloh was in fact completely destroyed?

---

For reference see the sources in [this article](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/mikdash2/51mikdash.htm) including: Yirmiyahu 7:12-15, and 26:6,9, Zevachim 118b, Rambam on Mishnayos Zevachim 14:7. CF the [Hebrew wiki entry](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94#.D7.94.D7.97.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.91.D7.9F)

Comment: Jeremiah chapter ~26 says so almost explicitly.

Comment: [Rashi Tehilim 74:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=269) says "Pelishtim Hechrivu Shilo"

Comment: Counter-evidence:  אמר רבי חייא בר אבין אמר רבי יהושע בן קרחה סח לי זקן אחד פעם אחת הלכתי לשילה והרחתי ריח קטורת מבין כותליה http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=39b&format=text

Comment: i don't believe Mishkan Shilo was ever destroyed. It was simply put out of use when Dawid moved the Aron haQodesh to Jerusalem

Comment: And wasn't that the backup Aron of wood, anyway, not the real Aron of gold from the Mishkan?

Comment: @Aaron David moved the Aron from Givah, not Shilo.

Comment: Jeremiah mentions that God destroyed Shiloh (7:14 26:6,9). See too Psalms 78:60.

Comment: The word, לחרב, can also mean that it was changed from it's previous state of being to a completely new state of being. This is the same explanation the Lubavitcher Rebbe gave to Yalkut Shimoni on Isaiah 499 which says the whole world is destroyed. This would suggest that each move of the Mishkan was an ascent in it's level of holiness until it became G-d's chosen and permanent house in Yerushalyim.

Comment: @YaacovDeane would that mean that each place in which the mishkan stayed, there is a residual level of holiness because the holiness of the place was raised by the presence of the mishkan and ma'alin bakodesh v'ein moridin. Would there be any residual holiness to each site?

Comment: @rosends Not as I understand it. When the Mishkan departed a place, nothing remained.

Answer (score 3):

''ותנא כשמת עלי הכהן חרבה שילה ובאו לנוב' 
And a tanna taught: When Eli the priest died, Shiloh was destroyed and the Jews arrived at Nov, where they erected the Tabernacle.[zevachim 118b]

it was not completely destroyed there still was some kind of a structure there 
אמר רבי חייא בר אבין אמר רבי יהושע בן קרחה סח לי זקן אחד פעם אחת הלכתי לשילה והרחתי
ריח קטורת מבין כותליה''יומא לט ב
 Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Avin said that Rabbi Yehoshua ben Korcḥa said: An old man reported to me: One time I went to Shiloh, and I smelled the smell of the incense from between its walls.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer Sholom. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!